# how to make text inside textfield bold by default

Tags: fonts, macros, hyperref, textfield

I tried various combinations (fontWeight=bfseries, font=bfseries) in the new command definition to make the input text boldface by default but have not succeeded so far. I would be grateful for any suggestions.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref,stackengine}
\newcommand{\TF}[2][5em]{\TextField[borderwidth=-0.2pt,
                           width=#1,
                           height=#1,  
                           charsize=12pt,
                           backgroundcolor=white!50!white,
                           color=black!100!black,
                           bordercolor=white!20!white,
                           name=#2
                           charWeight=\bfseries
                          ]{}}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\TF[12em, height=12pt, charsize=12pt,
     color=black!100!black, bordercolor=1 1 1]{d}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it is difficult. Unlike for the normal text in a PDF the glyphs in a text field are not taken from an embedded resource but are something that the PDF viewer must generate on the fly (after all nobody knows which characters a user will input in such a field). The PDF reference doesn't specify many details about how such a font resources should be build but leave it to the processors and that means that it depends a lot on the PDF viewer.

hyperref therefore doesn't offer many options, you can try to set the font size and the color but that's more or less it.

With l3pdffield-testphase you can also specify a font name, but as I wrote above it is not garantied that every viewer will honor that setting. If they can't find the font they can fallback to something else (or simply ignore the setting anyway):

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVuSans}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Some bold text}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdffield_textfield:n{name=name,font=DejaVuSans-Bold,width=5cm}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

With adobe reader this gives this font in the field:

[image]