# Creating Dynamic PDF with a Button to add a TextField

Tags: pdf, dynamic

I haven't created a PDF using LaTeX but is currently learning how to use it. The purpose of using LaTeX for PDF generation is for creating a PDF Form that can take inputs. The PDF that I will be creating will be an Employee Application Form. I plan to make the PDF Form dynamic by placing TextFields (My recent searches in the internet that I can embed text fields into the PDF). I also wanted to embed a button within the PDF which will automatically generate a TextField. I would like to ask if it is possible, if possible what frameworks, libraries m ust be used, or if it is not possible. Thank you for your responses

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by generate a text field? You can certainly make a PDF with text fields. These can have default content and are customisable. But I'm not sure you can change the structure of the PDF via a button on the fly and it isn't clear how this could work. But I'm also not at all sure whether that's what you mean.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the response. I am actually looking to implement a button inside a pdf that will change the PDF structure on the fly. Unfortunately it looks like it cannot be implemented according to your comment.

Comment: It's not even clear how it would work. If you add something in, that changes everything: page breaks, cross-references, hyperlinks .... Almost everything would need to be recreated and that's obviously not possible.

Comment: You might find the eforms package useful.

Comment: Hi, @JohnKormylo. Supposedly, I want to implement a button that can dynamically add a textfield unto the PDF, can it be done using the eforms package?

Comment: You do lots of stuff with PDF fields if you can use javascript. But this is not on topic here, you would have to ask on sites that discuss PDF fields. Once you know what you want you can then ask how to produce that also with LaTeX. But generally: you say you don't know LaTeX and you don't know much about PDF fields. While is easy to add a textfield (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708609/238) complex fields are not easy at all. That means that you have many hours of research and learning before you. So consider if you are the right man for this task.

Comment: You might be able to reveal a hidden text field, but the location has to be fixed when the PDF is created.   Or you could create multiple documents and use hyperref to jump between them.